# searchableListView when coupled with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to create a searchable list view. Initially, it worked fine hardcoded array. But when I used ArrayList and populated it with json, it is now not showing any search results. It is now loading the list properly but the search is not working. 
Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ProgressDialog pd;
Toolbar mToolbar;
ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
ListView mListView;
TextView mEmptyView;
PatientListAdapter adapter = null;
String clinic_id, response;
public BufferedReader reader = null;
public ArrayList<PatientListDetails> patientListDetailsList;
private String url = "http://192.168.2.4/projectFolder1/FetchData/getDataList.php?";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle("View Project List");

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setTitle("Niramaya");
    pd.setMessage("Fetching patient list. Please wait....");


    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyView);

    new GetPatientListTask().execute(url+"cid=1");


//        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
//                   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months_array));
//        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//
//        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }

//        });

//

//        mListView.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);
}

private class GetPatientListTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,List<PatientListDetails>> {

    List<PatientListDetails> patientDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<PatientListDetails> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        StringBuffer buffer = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        JSONArray jsonArray;

        try{

            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(stream));

            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }


            jsonArray = new JSONArray(buffer.toString());


            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                response = jsonObject.getString("status");

                if(response.equals("0")){
                    PatientListDetails patientListDetails = new PatientListDetails();


patientListDetails.setStatus(jsonObject.getString("status"));

patientListDetails.setPatient_id(jsonObject.getString("patient_id"));

patientListDetails.setFull_name(jsonObject.getString("full_name"));

patientListDetails.setGender(jsonObject.getString("gender"));


//Log.e("name",jsonObject.getString("full_name"));
                    patientDetailsList.add(patientListDetails);
                }

            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return patientDetailsList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<PatientListDetails> s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();
         adapter = new 
PatientListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.patient_list,s);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}

class MyViewHolder{
    TextView tvFull_name,tvGender,btn;
    EditText pid;
    MyViewHolder(View v){
        tvFull_name = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.patient_name);
        tvGender = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.patient_gender);
        pid = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.patient_id);
        btn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_view);

    }
}

public class PatientListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements 
Filterable{


    int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PatientListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, 
@NonNull List<PatientListDetails> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        patientListDetailsList= (ArrayList<PatientListDetails>) 
objects;
        this.resource=resource;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                   return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                try {
                    patientListDetailsList = (ArrayList<PatientListDetails>) results.values;
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    Log.e("Error",e.toString());
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_list, null);
            holder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }


            if (holder != null) {


holder.tvFull_name.setText(patientListDetailsList.get(position).getFull_name());

            }

//                if (holder != null) {

//                    holder.tvGender.setText(patientListDetailsList.get(position).getGender());

//                }

//                final String pat_id = patientListDetailsList.get(position).getPatient_id();




//            if (holder != null) {

//                holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//                    @Override

//                    public void onClick(View v) {



//                    }

//                });

//            }

        return convertView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbarmenu, menu);

    MenuItem mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search");

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


}
```

I tried with many other options here on stack over flow but nothing worked. So I had to ask this question.

Comment: Your `performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)` method is returning null. You should add some logic to filter your data in that method

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for text-matching based filter, you can use the following code -

```
@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }
```

Comment: What does originalData represent here?

Comment: I am getting a Null pointer exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
for this link of code
 int count = list.size();

Comment: `originalData` here is the list of Patients you are fetching from your server